# Google Map static won't show my location

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I'am trying this link

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.789728,51.468728&size=640x640&key=[my API key]
```

but, it won't show my location it's only displaying world map
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the zoom parameter

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#URL_Parameters

Please try the following URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.789728%2C51.468728&zoom=18&size=640x640&key=YOUR_API_KEY